# Sort a List of String[]s?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, sorting

In Java I have `List<String[]> myList` and I would like to be able to sort it in various ways. For example sort it by `row[0]`, or maybe `row[0]` and then by `row[1]`, etc, where `row[i]` is the `String[]` at index `i`.

Can this be done or does Java not support it?

Comment: Have a look at the static methods in [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  E.g., to sort by the third element in each array, you could use the comparator `List<String[]> list = ... ; list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a[2]));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of JDK1.7. You can change index in the comparator implementation .

```
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

myList.add(new String[]{"a","g","x"});
myList.add(new String[]{"c","f","y"});
myList.add(new String[]{"b","d","z"});

Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Huh, wasn't aware you could pass Comparators as an argument to Collections.sort(). Cool! Thanks.